# using a web browser, how to lie to a website that we are in fullscreen?

Tags: browser-addons, fullscreen, facebook

Many websites change the way they display content according to whether the browser has entered full screen or is a regular window.

for example Facebook shows an image one way in a regular window and different in fullscreen

[image]

vs

[image]

How do I lie the site (any site) that I've entered full screen when I press "**Enter Full Screen**" button of the site, so I keep the site inside the regular window and make it think it's now full screen ?

Any browser solution is okay (IE/Edge, Safari, Firefox, Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on how the site is detecting "fullscreen".  They could be using CSS media queries, javascript or something else.  In the case of the Facebook example you are actually initiating a function in their code (clicking the full screen button) so it really could be doing anything.

I think the chances of finding what you want are slim, but this is where I would start: http://weboverride.com/

It's a great chrome extension.  You could use it to add a CSS class or run a javascript function on the specific sites you desire this behavior on.